# C Win32 API display Opencv Image cv::Mat + Resizing, results in distorted, wrong colored images

Tags: c, windows, opencv, winapi, win32gui

So I've been looking for some simple code, on how I can display opencv images in a windows window, without using extra libraries. Most solutions that I have found use the StretchDIBits() method of the Windows API. This works fine, until I resize the window, although I call my display function after WM_SIZE and resize my image with opencv before I display it with StretchDIBits(). Sometimes the image is displayed fine, but most of the time it's distorted or even in greyscale, even though it is a RGB image.

The image resizing with opencv works fine. When I display the resized image with `cv::imshow("test", imgResized);` the image is displayed as expected in the same size as the resized window.

#### This is an image at application launch (works fine)

[image: This is an image at application launch (works fine)]

#### This is an image after resizing the window (distorted and greyscaled)

[image: This is an image after resizing the window (distorted and greyscaled)]

#### My Code

```c
VOID ImgviewShowImg(IMGVIEW* imgView)
{
    if(imgView->img == NULLPTR)
    {
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat imgResized; 
    POSZ inner  = GetInnerPosSize(imgView);
    INT width  = inner.w;
    INT height = inner.h;

    cv::resize(*imgView->img, imgResized, cv::Size(width, height), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    
    INT bytesPerPixel = imgResized.elemSize();

    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
    memset(&bmpInfo, 0, sizeof(bmpInfo));
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth  = width;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes   = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = (bytesPerPixel * 8);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 100;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 100;

    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    memset(&paintStruct, 0, sizeof(paintStruct));

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(imgView->hWnd, &paintStruct);

    INT result = StretchDIBits(hdc, // HDC              hdc,
        0,                          // int              xDest,
        0,                          // int              yDest,
        width,                      // int              DestWidth,
        height,                     // int              DestHeight,
        0,                          // int              xSrc,
        0,                          // int              ySrc,
        width,                      // int              SrcWidth,
        height,                     // int              SrcHeight,
        imgResized.data,            // const            VOID       *lpBits,
        &bmpInfo,                   // const            BITMAPINFO *lpbmi,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,             // UINT             iUsage,
        SRCCOPY                     // DWORD            rop
    );

    EndPaint(imgView->hWnd, &paintStruct);
}
```

Comment: Rows in a bitmap need to be aligned to `DWORD` boundaries, i.e. each row must start at a memory address that's a multiple of 4.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you so much. I obviously did not know this and I don't know how long it would have taken me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the anwser of [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) and a quick google search where I found this https://gist.github.com/AhiyaHiya/6e455a3a6c846766f1017044131bfab7 with the simple solution `resize(frame, frame, Size(frame.cols / 4 * 4, frame.rows));`

I finally got my code to work and it now looks like this:

```c
VOID ImgviewShowImg(IMGVIEW* imgView)
{
    if(imgView->img == NULLPTR)
    {
        return;
    }

    RECT clientRect;
    GetClientRect(imgView->hWnd, &clientRect);

    INT wndWidth  = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
    INT wndHeight = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;
    FLOAT32 aspectRatio = (FLOAT32) wndHeight / (FLOAT32) wndWidth;

    INT imgWidth  = (INT) ((wndWidth / 4) * 4);
    INT imgHeight = (INT) (imgWidth * aspectRatio);

    cv::Mat imgResized; 
    cv::resize(*imgView->img, imgResized, cv::Size(imgWidth, imgHeight), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    
    INT bytesPerPixel = imgResized.elemSize();

    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
    memset(&bmpInfo, 0, sizeof(bmpInfo));
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth  = imgWidth;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = imgHeight;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes   = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = (bytesPerPixel * 8);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 100;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 100;

    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    memset(&paintStruct, 0, sizeof(paintStruct));

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(imgView->hWnd, &paintStruct);

    INT result = StretchDIBits(hdc, // HDC              hdc,
        0,                          // int              xDest,
        0,                          // int              yDest,
        wndWidth,                      // int              DestWidth,
        wndHeight,                     // int              DestHeight,
        0,                          // int              xSrc,
        0,                          // int              ySrc,
        imgWidth,                      // int              SrcWidth,
        imgHeight,                     // int              SrcHeight,
        imgResized.data,            // const            VOID       *lpBits,
        &bmpInfo,                   // const            BITMAPINFO *lpbmi,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,             // UINT             iUsage,
        SRCCOPY                     // DWORD            rop
    );

    EndPaint(imgView->hWnd, &paintStruct);
}
```